# Best practices to drop & update primary/unique keys on production without having a downtime

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am implementing data partitioning on mysql server(8.0).

As a "must-have requirement of partitioning" I have to add my partition key as a primary key, which is `created_at` in my table. eg:

```
alter table notifications drop primary key, add primary key(`id`, `created_at`);
```

In above query, `id` is an auto-increment primary key. I have more than 10M entries in table.
Mysql won't allow live updates on schemas; it will lock the table when I run `alter` command.

At the same time, I can take a downtime for this process. Please guide the best approach to take this live.

I tried generating same amount of data on my local using "Faker" library & while running alter query on it. I observed it taking more than 2 hours for this process.

`Schema`

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `seq_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `doc_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `page_no` int DEFAULT '1',
  `file_store` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `s_f_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `f_store` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'GCP',
  `purged` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`seq_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `doc_id` (`doc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
ALTER TABLE `data `
PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at))
(
  PARTITION `partition_2020` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 00:00:00')),
  PARTITION `partition_2021` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01 00:00:00')), 
  PARTITION `partition_2022` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00')), 
  PARTITION `partition_2022` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-31 00:00:00')),
  PARTITION `partition_future` VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Comment: Use an online schema change tool. There are two good free options: [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) or [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost). Like any new tool, test them out on data that is not production until you learn how to use them.

Comment: I am voting to reopen it, but I think it belongs in Database Adminstrators

Comment: "In above query, id is an auto-increment primary key" -- this contradicts the table declaration.  Please make them consistent.

Comment: Will you be using Partitioning to do efficient `DROP PARTITION` based on `created_at`?  Or some other reason?

Comment: @RickJames yes, i'll be using Partitioning to do efficient DROP_PARTITION based on created at. Partition query also update in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are very concerned about the lock time, then I suggest you use the master-slave replication. Basically, it is a master-slave switching time, which is very short.

Comment: It would be better if Primary-Primary were already set up.

Comment: @dogs cute can you please explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

Both changing the PK *and* adding `PARTITIONing` require a full copy and re-index of the data.  This will be slow.  But...  Let's talk about whether the Partitioning will provide any benefit.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- both currently and after adding partitioning.  See also [*Partition*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

If, on the other hand, you decide that Partitioning is really needed, and the table is growing, then the sooner you do it, the less time it will take.

If you will be purging some old data as you do the conversion, then I suggest doing everything at once:

```
CREATE TABLE new_t (
    ... ); -- with new PK and partitioning.
INSERT INTO new_t
    SELECT * FROM t
        WHERE date >= ...; -- to purge old data by not copying it over
```

But even before doing that, let's see the CREATEs, there may be more advice to fold into the copy.

Also note that Partitioning does not allow for `UNIQUE` keys, nor for `FOREIGN KEYs`.  We can discuss that further after seeing the `CREATE`.

Also -- Do you have a "natural" PK?  That is, can you get rid of `id`?

**More**

While changing the PK, can you simply remove the `seq_id` (auto_inc) column?  Or do you need it for some other reason?

Comment: i can't take downtime.

Comment: And you have not set up Replication, either?  Then let's focus on _why_ Partitioning should be added.

Comment: Schema updated in question.

Comment: **And...**

When adding partitioning, you will also need to add `created_at` to 

    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)

Notice that, by adding a column to both unique keys, the uniqueness constraint is destroyed.  Do you actually need the uniqueness?  For example, do you use `INSERT IGNORE` or catch "dup key" errors?

Comment: yes, i need uniqueness.

Comment: @PankajArora - With partitioning, `UNIQUE` may not provide the uniqueness constraint (because of having to add the PK on).  You _could_ do the check in a separate check.  Or this could be another argument for _not_ use Partitioning.